# SQL to UNION ALL n times depending on rows of table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that has quiz entries submitted by users. Each row has: date, id, source and a score.

I want to create a report, per source, that calculates the average score for each day taking into account all users, even the ones that didn't reply on that day by considering their latest response.

Right now I have one query that can simply pull all quiz responses for a given day, source and user - if a user submitted multiple quizzes on the same day the latest one is retrieved:

**Query**

```
      select
        id
        score,
        submission_date,
        source
      from
        quiz
      WHERE
        id != ""
      qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY source, submission_date), id ORDER BY submission_date DESC) = 1;
```

Now, for each row that is returned from the query above I want to UNION ALL with a similar query as above but where the submission_date, instead of being the latest, should be <= the submission_date of the row it is going to 'union' with.

In another words, the query above could return 'n' rows, each row from table A should have UNION ALL 'n' times with a query that will base itself on the row submission date it is going to UNION ALL with:

```
Table A:
row 1
row 2
row 3
...
row n

Final table:
row 1
(multiple rows from UNION ALL)
row 2
(multiple rows from UNION ALL)
row 3
(multiple rows from UNION ALL)
...
row n
(multiple rows from UNION ALL)
```

I don't know if UNION ALL is the solution here but this is what I could think of.

**Edit**

This is the output of the query above that reads from table named quiz:

| id | score | submission_date | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 30 | 2022-09-16 | foxmedia |
| user2 | 29 | 2022-09-16 | foxmedia |
| user3 | 44 | 2022-09-14 | foxmedia |
| user4 | 58 | 2022-09-13 | foxmedia |
| user5 | 94 | 2022-09-13 | branding |
| user2 | 25 | 2022-09-11 | foxmedia |
| user1 | 21 | 2022-09-11 | foxmedia |
| user4 | 50 | 2022-09-10 | foxmedia |
| user2 | 23 | 2022-09-10 | foxmedia |
| user1 | 22 | 2022-09-10 | foxmedia |
| user5 | 90 | 2022-09-09 | branding |

As you can see, on 2022-09-16 user1 and user2 have submitted responses but the average for this day should consider the last response from all other users on foxmedia as if they answered the quiz on that same day, which means including on the average calculation rows from user3 on 2022-09-14 and user4 on 2022-09-13. user5 should not count for the average as the source is not branding but foxmedia which should have a separate average, which in this case would only include data from user5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample and expected data? Just so this could be easier visualized by the community members.

Comment: I tried to improve the description above as you suggested, please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have scores for each user, but only for some days.
- For each day you want to have an entry for all users.
- The score for each user is the score of the day. If on a day an user has no score, take the last value from the past.

We start building some sample data. Then we cross join this with every date `all_dates` in the dataset. Next we group the data by the `all_dates` and user id. For obtaining the last entry of each user, an array of the scores is build. The `if` case is needed to not use score data from the future.

```sql
with tbl as 
(
Select "user1" as id, 30 as score, date("2022-09-16") as submission_date, "foxmedia" as S,
 union all Select "user2", 29 ,date("2022-09-16"), "foxmedia",
 union all Select "user3", 44 ,date("2022-09-14"), "foxmedia",
 union all Select "user4", 58 ,date("2022-09-13"), "foxmedia",
 union all Select "user5", 94 ,date("2022-09-13"), "branding",
 union all Select "user2", 25 ,date("2022-09-11"), "foxmedia",
 union all Select "user1", 21 ,date("2022-09-11"), "foxmedia",
 union all Select "user4", 50 ,date("2022-09-10"), "foxmedia",
 union all Select "user2", 23 ,date("2022-09-10"), "foxmedia",
 union all Select "user1", 22 ,date("2022-09-10"), "foxmedia",
 union all Select "user5", 90 ,date("2022-09-09"), "branding"
)
select 
S,
all_dates,
id,
array_agg(submission_date order by submission_date desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] as last_date,
array_agg(if(submission_date<=all_dates,score,null) ignore nulls order by submission_date desc limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] as last_score,

from tbl
cross join (select distinct submission_date as all_dates from tbl)
group by 1,2,3
order by 1 desc,2 desc,3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Samuel you helped immensely!